# Не происходит авторизация пользователя через SecurityBundle

Tags: php, symfony2

Здравствуйте.

Очень нужна помощь в диагностике ошибки при авторизации, так как моих знаний Symfony совершенно не хватает.

Приложение строится на Symfony 2.8.8

Кратко по сути: при попытке авторизации, проиходит редирект на страницу логина, а авторизация не происходит.

Вот лог app/logs/dev.log:

```
[2016-08-04 11:37:17] request.INFO: Matched route "BloggerBlogBundle_security_check". {"route_parameters":{"_route":"BloggerBlogBundle_security_check"},"request_uri":"http://symfony_blog.workspace/web/app_dev.php/login_check"} []
[2016-08-04 11:37:17] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /var/www/workspace/symfony_blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:73, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): Username \"john.doe\" does not exist. at /var/www/workspace/symfony_blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php:109)"} []
[2016-08-04 11:37:17] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"/login"} []
[2016-08-04 11:37:17] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"7677b7","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://symfony_blog.workspace/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/7677b7"} []
```

Ключевой момент здесь, как мне кажется:

```
Username \"john.doe\" does not exist.
```

Конфиг app/config/config.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
        Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 10

    providers:
        main:
            entity: 
                class: Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        main: 
            pattern: /.*
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout: true
            security: true
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: /admin/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Вот route.yml:

```
BloggerBlogBundle_comment_create:
    path: /comment/{blog_id}
    defaults: { _controller: 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:create' }
    requirements:
        method: POST
        blog_id: \d+

BloggerBlogBundle_security_login:
    path: /login
    defaults: {_controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Security:login }

BloggerBlogBundle_security_check:
    path:    /login_check

BloggerBlogBundle_security_logout:
    path: /logout

BloggerBlogBindle_admin_home:
    path: /admin/
    defaults: { controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Admin:index }
```

Сущность Role:

```
<?php

// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Role.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface
    {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * This method is needed to implement RoleInterface
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Сущность User:

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collection\ArraCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
     *                joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *                inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
     */
    protected $userRoles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date_added;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ports    = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->setDateAdded(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * Clear user privileges
     **/
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @return array of Role object
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->getUserRoles()->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Compare one user to another user
     * and determine if its same user
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return boolean True if equals and false otherwise
     */
    public function equals(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return md5($this->getUsername()) == md5($user->getUsername());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param boolean $status
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateAdded
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateAdded
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDateAdded($dateAdded)
    {
        $this->date_added = $dateAdded;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateAdded
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateAdded()
    {
        return $this->date_added;
    }

    /**
     * Get user roles
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getUserRoles()
    {
        return $this->userRoles;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Add userRole
     *
     * @param \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Role $userRole
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addUserRole(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Role $userRole)
    {
        $this->userRoles[] = $userRole;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove userRole
     *
     * @param \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Role $userRole
     */
    public function removeUserRole(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Role $userRole)
    {
        $this->userRoles->removeElement($userRole);
    }
}
```

Фикстура для добавления роли и пользователя UserFixture:

```
<?php

// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/UserFixture.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\DataFixture\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User;
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder;

class UserFixture implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // Create role
        $role = new Role();
        $role->setName('ROLE_ADMIN');

        $manager->persist($role);

        // Create user
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername('john.doe');
        $user->setStatus(true);
        $user->setSalt(md5(time()));

        // encrypt and set password to user
        // this settings coincide to configuration
        $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', true, 10);
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword('admin', $user->getSalt());

        $user->setPassword($password);

        $user->getUserRoles()->add($role);

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Размышления:
В конфигурации я указал провайдер main -> entity ..., но в логах указывается что юзер не найден в InMemoryUserProvider:

```
[2016-08-04 11:37:17] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /var/www/workspace/symfony_blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:73, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): **Username \"john.doe\" does not exist. at /var/www/workspace/symfony_blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php:109**)"} []
```

Складывается такое ощущения что обработчик авторизации просто не подключает сущность User.

От безысходности пробовал по-разному подключать сущность в config.yml:

```
providers:
    main:
        entity: 
            class: BloggerBlogBundle:User
            property: username
```

и так:

```
providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: BloggerBlogBundle:User, property: username }
```

Буду премного благодарен за любую помощь или подсказку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файрволе `main` не указан провайдер, поэтому по-дефолту используется `in_memory` провайдер, а в нём такого юзера нет.

Надо указать ваш провайдер (provider: main):

```
security:
    providers:
        main:
            entity: 
                class: Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        main: 
            pattern: /.*
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout: true
            security: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: main
```